# Works great when all tags are present (DOM)

Tags: php, html, dom

This works great when all tags are present:

```
$data='<a href="http://somelink.com"><img src="http://somelink.com/image.png"></a>'   
$html = $data;
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$data = ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a')[0]->getAttribute('href'));
```

The output is

```
http://somelink.com
```

However if the first tag is missing

```
$data='a href="http://somelink.com"><img src="http://somelink.com/image.png"></a>'
```

The output is blank and it actually makes the whole page go blank. Is there a way to still have the same output

```
http://somelink.com
```

even if the first tag is missing?

Comment: what you exactly want?

Comment: "Is there a way to still have the same output even if the first tag is missing?" Not that hard to understand...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible. Because `$dom->getElementsByTagName('a')[0]->getAttribute('href')` by doing this you are storing the Attribute value of an HTML tag `<a>` in the variable `$data`. but if you remove the HTML tag then it's not possible to get the Attribute value of a tag That do not exist. 
Apart from this, If you still want to do this by removing the HTML tag then You should use **String Manipulation FUnctions** to extract the URL from a string stored in php variable. 
REGEX is also a solution to your problem.
Here is the code that will extract the URL from your string.

```
$data='a href="http://somelink.com"><img src="http://somelink.com/image.png"></a>';
preg_match_all('@((https?://)?([-\\w]+\\.[-\\w\\.]+)+\\w(:\\d+)?(/([-\\w/_\\.]*(\\?\\S+)?)?)*)@', $data, $match);
echo $match[0][0]."<br>"; //URL of <a> tag
echo $match[0][1]; //URL of image tag
```

Comment: I tried to do this with: 
    
`preg_match('/"([^"]+)"/', $data, $href);

$data = $href[1]; ` however when the first tag is missing, it strips everything. Is there a way to make sure that if the first tag is missing it simply outputs the original url without the first tag?

Comment: @MrK See my edited answer now. This will give you your expected result i.e `http://somelink.com`

Comment: WOW!! I just tested it and it works on all levels. I mean I tried several links that had a class="test" and target="_blank", with and without the first tag and the output was `http://somelink.com` That's so cool. I've been at it for the last 3 hours. Thought I'd never make it work. Thank you so much.

Comment: Can you help me with one more thing? It seems like your preg_match_all doesn't work if www. is present. It has to be part of the code since some urls will have https:// and some http://www. I'd appreciate if you could add this to your solution.

Comment: When I put something like (note the www): `<a href="http://www.somelink.com"><img src="http://www.somelink.com/image.png"></a>` the output is `http://www` the rest of the link is stripped. Can it be fixed?

Comment: I just edited my answer. replace your `preg_match_all` with the current one

Comment: this will surely work. check it and let me. I already tested it on my end. Here it is working flawlessly even with `www`

Comment: show me your code. paste your `preg_match_all()` here

Answer (score 1):

No because then you don't have an HTML element tag, you have characters with spaces and quotes.

Comment: But why is it "killing" the whole page? Can at least that be fixed? I wouldn't mind if the output was the same as the original link without the tag. But when it all goes blank, that's an issue.

Comment: Unfortunately no. Without the opening `<` you no longer have valid HTML and the vast majority of parsers will not recognize it as such.

Comment: @MrK: The text may look like HTML to your human eyes, but to a browser, or DOMDocument, armed with only a left-to-right parser, `'a href="...">'` is indistinguishable from `'a friend in need'`. You no longer have an `a` element, so `getElementsByTagName('a')` simply isn't going to find anything. Best you can do, if you can't rely on the source markup getting something this simple right, is extract the URL directly from the input without using DOMDocument at all.

Comment: @zainul abdeen 's solution does the job.